# Why the unary * operator does not have a constraint "the operand shall not be a pointer to void"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, void, dereference

C2x, 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, Constraints, 2:

> The operand of the unary * operator shall have pointer type.

Why there is no constraint "the operand shall not be a pointer to `void`"?

---

Though it can be deduced from:

C2x, 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, Semantics, 4:

> The **unary * operator** denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it **points to an object, the result is an lvalue** designating the object.

C2x, 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, 1:

> An **lvalue** is an expression (with an **object type other than void**) that potentially designates an object; ...

Comment: Because you cant dereference something that does not have the type. Same applies to the pointer arithmetic. (GCC has extension which allows pointer arithmetic on pointers to void, treating them same as pointers to char)

Comment: @0 The OP knows it, hence the question, why this is not a part of the "constraints" of the indirection operator.

Comment: @EugeneSh. then he is asking wrong people. Only the guys who are writing the standard can answer this question  :). But I think that the Sherlock Holmes way is sufficient as all programmers know to do not dereference the void pointer :)

Comment: @0___________ The [language lawyer] tag is for precisely this kind of rumination.

Comment: @0 Could be. But the answer might be hidden in your first comment. Making it a hard constraint will make the mentioned extension impossible (like `sizeof(*void_ptr)`) .

Comment: @EugeneSh. good guess

Comment: Why should it have such a constraint? What problem would it solve?

Comment: Clang does not appear to agree with the claim that some such constraint can be deduced from other rules. It compiles `void *foo(void *p) { return &*p; }` without complaint, even with `-Wall -pedantic -std=c17`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And neither should it complain, according to the C11 Draft I quoted. (PS: I guess I was composing my answer while you were composing/posting your comment with the `&*p` example.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Should gcc consider canceling `warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer` for `&*p`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One *possible* (though somewhat contrived, I'll admit) case where adding your 'suggested' constraint would break code is where the `&` and `*` operators are concatenated. In such cases, an expression such as `a = &*p`, where `p` is a `void*` type, *is* allowed.

From [this Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2731.pdf), *immediately* following the section in your first citation (bold emphasis mine):

> **Semantics**
> 3     The unary `&` operator yields the address of its
> operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type
> ‘‘pointer to type’’. ***If the operand is the result of a unary `*`
> operator, neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated***
> and the result is as if both were omitted, ***except that the
> constraints on the operators still apply*** and the result is not an
> lvalue. …

I can't, currently, think of a use-case for that `&*` combination (on a `void*` or any other pointer type) – but it *may* occur in code that is "auto-generated" and/or uses conditional macro expansion(s).

Comment: There seems to be a draft on the open-std website: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2731.pdf

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks - edited. (The actual wording is unchanged between the two drafts, fortunately.)

Comment: The difference between `p` and `&*p` is the first is an lvalue while the second is not. Maybe some use case can be derived for this purpose.

Comment: `&*p` could also be used as a compile time assertion that `p` is a pointer or an array, ie: not a number union or structure.

Comment: @chqrlie Re: "compile time assertion": any example?

Comment: eg: `#define ASSERT_PTR_OR_ARRAY(p)   ((void)"must have pointer"+!sizeof&*p)`

Comment: _I can't, currently, think of a use-case for that &* combination (on a void* or any other pointer type)_ The motivation for this rule has always been `&arr[arr_length]`, so that it is equivalent to `(arr + arr_length)` and no `*` is applied to past-the-end pointer.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Good point! because `a[b]` is syntactically equivalent to `*(a + b)`,

Comment: In fact, the paragraph I cite continues with ... *Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator. Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.*