# Is an lvalue required to have a complete type?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, lvalue, incomplete-type

Is an lvalue required to have a complete type? If no, then is `*x` where `x` has an incomplete type valid?

Note: for "[modifiable lvalue](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1)" there is (emphasis added):

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, **does not have an incomplete type**, ...

This code:

```
struct s* x;
void f(void)
{
    *x;
}
```

leads (mostly) to errors:

```
$ gcc -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<source>:4:9: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct x'

$ clang -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<source>:4:2: error: incomplete type 'struct x' where a complete type is required

$ icc -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<source>(4): error: incomplete type is not allowed

$ cl /std:c11 /Za
<nothing>
```

However, why these errors?

Here is how I see it: the operand of the unary `*` operator is a pointer type, the result is an lvalue designating the object with the incomplete type `struct x`. However, is an lvalue required to have a complete type?

UPD: It seems that the reason is to support `&*x`, for which all the compilers produce no diagnostics.

Comment: `*x;` is generating / might generate a read access to `*x` in order to "evaluate" it. In order to know what kind of access it has to generate, it needs to know it's type. See somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658582/is-volatile-t0x1234-guaranteed-to-translate-into-read-instruction

Comment: [Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, the unary `&` operator, etc. etc. … an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion. … If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is undefined.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2)

Comment: I'd say dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029394/in-c-language-is-it-semantically-possible-to-create-an-lvalue-with-incomplete-t

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are always complete types. But they can point to incomplete types. In this case you may not dereference a pointer because the compiler does not know how to represented the pointed object that is how to represent the corresponding lvalue that designates the object.. The size of the object of the incomplete type is unknown

Comment: However, there is no constraint "shall have pointer to coplete type". I guess that this is to support `&*x`. Here is a relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71022416/1778275).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with dereferencing an incomplete pointer type is that, because the compiler doesn't know the "shape" of the memory behind it (in this case specifically, the size of the memory allocated that can be safely accessed) there's almost nothing you can do with it. That pointer can even come from a `malloc(0)`, which isn't safe (under some implementations) to dereference with *any* size.

Now I say almost nothing because you somehow stumbled upon pretty much the only useful thing you can do with an incomplete pointer type dereference: nothing. Specifically, you dereference it and then don't use it. I could see a world in which this is implemented as a null check followed by a null access violation signal (or an exception in C++). But that is such an incredibly fringe case, and borderline useless at that, that I doubt anyone would bother to implement it.